# react native picker display after the value of array updated

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native i have one problem. first of all i will explain my work. i have one array object initially have some value. componentWillMount function will get the value from my database in json format. I parse that json to store in my array of object. After that i want to see that value in my picker list label.

The problem was only the initial value is shown in my picker list. I need to display an value after stored array object from my database parse value.

this is my code

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
        a: [{"id": 0, "windID": "1", "windname": "a"},],
        windFormID:'',
  }
}
componentWillMount(){
   return  fetch('http://api.kiot.katomaran.com/api/v1/wind_farms', {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  })

.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  if (responseJson.status === true){
  for ( i = 0,len = responseJson.data.length ; i < len; i++) { 
    if(i===0)
    {
        this.state.a[0]={'id':i,'windID' : responseJson.data[i].id,'windname' : responseJson.data[i].name}
    }
    else{
    this.state.a.push({'id':i,'windID' : responseJson.data[i].id,'windname' : responseJson.data[i].name}) 
    }
  }
  console.log(this.state.a)

  }
  else{
    alert(responseJson.message); 
  }
})
```

}

```
    <Picker 
            selectedValue={this.state.windFormID}
            style={styles.button} 
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
            this.setState({windFormID: itemValue})}>
            {this.state.a.map((key, index) => {
            return(<Picker.Item label={key.windname} value={index} key= 
            {index}/>)
            })}
    </Picker>
```

yesterday someone help me to solve this problem. but that can't any issue.
I am totally stuck here over two days......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setState`  [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state)

```
    let newarray=[];
    for ( i = 0,len = responseJson.data.length ; i < len; i++) { 
        newarray.push({'id':i,'windID' : responseJson.data[i].id,'windname' : responseJson.data[i].name}) 
      }
     this.setState({a:newarray})
```

Comment: Bro i want to map particular item the value:{windID} for particular label:{windname}

Comment: @JAYARAM post different question for that

Comment: K bro finally very thanx